# BPF per CPU array is not zero initialized?

Tags: kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I want to use a `BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY` to count the number of packets received at the `SK_SKB` hook. I checked the map values using `bpftool map dump` right after creating the map, and it seems that for some CPUs, the values are not zero initialized.

Here is the map definition:

```
struct {
  __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
  __uint(max_entries, 1);
  __type(key, int);
  __type(value, __u64);
  __uint(pinning, LIBBPF_PIN_BY_NAME);
} request_count_map SEC(".maps");
```

And here is the output of `bpftool map dump`:

```
$ sudo bpftool map dump id 287
[{
        "key": 0,
        "values": [{
                "cpu": 0,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 1,
                "value": 94322157119214
            },{
                "cpu": 2,
                "value": 140730068914171
            },{
                "cpu": 3,
                "value": 94322160575280
            },{
                "cpu": 4,
                "value": 94322160592312
            },{
                "cpu": 5,
                "value": 94322160592512
            },{
                "cpu": 6,
                "value": 80
            },{
                "cpu": 7,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 8,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 9,
                "value": 140730068932048
            },{
                "cpu": 10,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 11,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 12,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 13,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 14,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 15,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 16,
                "value": 80
            },{
                "cpu": 17,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 18,
                "value": 0
            },{
                "cpu": 19,
                "value": 140730068932048
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

From the documentation ([here](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/map_array.html#:%7E:text=elements%20are%20pre%2Dallocated%20and%20zero%20initialized%20when%20created.) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html#:%7E:text=All%20array%20elements%20pre%2Dallocated%20and%20zero%20initialized)), it seems that the expected behavior is for the values to be zero initialized?

*Edit:* I realized that I was updating the map when loading it, as follows:

```
int index = 0;
__u64 value = 0;

// Get the svc_identifier_map fd.
reqcnt_map_fd = bpf_obj_get(reqcnt_map_filename);

// Add the svc identifier to the svc_identifier_map.
err = bpf_map_update_elem(respcnt_map_fd, &index, &value, BPF_ANY);
if (err) {
  goto fail;
}
```

However, the values should still be zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `bpf_map_update_elem` from userspace on a per-CPU map you need to provide a pointer to `{value type}[__NR_CPU__]` as value. In your case you provided a pointer to `__u64` which is significantly smaller. So libbpf essentially read stack/memory after your `value` until it had enough. So you wrote part of your stack / uninitialized memory into the map.